# FB.login produces flash error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the fbAsyncInit method for an iframe application that lives in a fan page tab

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      console.log('fb init');
    FB.init({
      appId  : 12345,
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

And when I call a register function to check permissions (this happens when a user clicks a button after the page is loaded)

```
register = function(){
console.log('starting login');
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
            console.log(response.session);
        } else {                
            console.log('Did not authorize');
        }
}, {perms:'email,publish_stream'});
```

};

Facebook loads the popup from: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb={session string variables and other junk here}

Which produces a flash error in IE only:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code=
```

My site has no flash in it

Hitting continue/dismiss may sometimes freeze IE causing me to end process, other times the popup goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution for the Flash problem. Please update `FB.init`:

```
FB.init({
      appId  : 12345,
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
      channelURL : 'http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/channel.html'
    });
```

In your domain root folder create `channel.html` and put only this code in it:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Now the Flash on Facebook works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Flash 10.2+ when using the Flash/FaceBook API you will get the following error.
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.

Flash 10.3 you get
Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code=

I am calling Facebook.login() from a flash application.  The login is successful, however this error seems to disrupt the process.  This issue is only affecting IE 8 and no other browsers.
I have tried the channelUrl, but across another domain as I do not have access to where the flash file is being served.  I am using Charles to map local.  Will this work?

Outside of that I am lost.  I'm not sure if the error is being triggered by my SWF or Facebook's proxy SWF.  So frustrating.  This was working a couple months ago.

Comment: Did you add the channel url as specified in the answer above?

Comment: I tested this morning, and I CAN CONFIRM.... THIS FIX WORKS.   Just make sure your channelUrl is located on the same domain..... Question... what if we need to regionalize the all.js?  Does the one included on the page superceed this one?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided above did not work for me. But this did which i found on another topic in stackoverflow (thanks to Sean Kinsey):

See this bug report : 
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15596
IE8, getLoginStatus never completes when flash XD is used - it sounds like it might be what you are experiencing.

In that case, make sure that your **fb-root div** is **not** being set to **visibility:hidden** or **display:none** as this will cause the XD Flash not to render

(i did add the channelURL as well)